# Arrays and measurement unit conversion

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io, text-files

```
using (read = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Sam Smith/Desktop/convert.txt"))
            {
                while (!read.EndOfStream)
                {
                    lineFromFile = read.ReadLine();
                    units = lineFromFile.Split(',');

                    if (units.Contains(splitEntry[0]) && units.Contains(splitEntry[1]))
                    {
                        firstUnit = units[0];
                        secondUnit = units[1];
                        userConvertValue = Convert.ToDouble(splitEntry[2]);
                        fileConvertValue = Convert.ToDouble(units[2]);
                        result = fileConvertValue * userConvertValue;
                    }
                    if (units.Contains(splitEntry[0]) && units.Contains(splitEntry[1]))
                    {
                        firstUnit = units[1];
                        secondUnit = units[0];
                        userConvertValue = Convert.ToDouble(splitEntry[2]);
                        fileConvertValue = Convert.ToDouble(units[2]);
                        result = userConvertValue / fileConvertValue;
                    }
                    if (!units.Contains(splitEntry[0]) || !units.Contains(splitEntry[1]))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error, measurement unit not recognised.");
                    }
```

Above I have a text file that contains types of unit measurement (pounds, ounces, miles and such), the text from this file is split into a string array.
The user enters two measurement units in the following format to convert to two units:
unit,unit,amount
In the text file, the conversion amount for two units is every third split string, like so:
unit,unit,2.80
unit,unit,1.27 (etc)

Is there a way of grouping each set of units and their conversion amounts? For example, if the user tries to convert two particular units, the program knows which conversion value to use when calculating the final result.
Might be a little vague, but it's difficult to explain.
EDIT: The user does not interact with the file, the program simply pulls the data from the file, which is then split into strings (',') and stored in an array.

Comment: -1: Unfortunately it's very vague, it doesn't help that there is a "text file", and "the user enters" things. Does the user enter things in to the text file? Can you provide a sample of the text file, why the user entered those values, and then tell us what the program is supposed to do with the data.

Comment: What is the purpose of the splitEntry array? I assume it's declared outside of this snippet.

Comment: The purpose of 'splitEntry' is to split the user's input into an array. The values of that array are then checked against the values of the 'units' array, using .contains()

Answer (score 0):

If I don't got you wrong, the following code should fulfill your requirements (it's very basic, no error handling etc.):

```
public enum Unit
{
  Pound,
  Kilo,
  Kilometer,
  Mile
}

public class UnitMapping
{

  public UnitMapping(Unit source, Unit target, double factor)
  {
    SourceUnit = source;
    TargetUnit = target;
    Factor = factor;
  }

  public Unit SourceUnit { get; private set; }

  public Unit TargetUnit { get; private set; }

  public double Factor { get; private set; }

}

public class UnitCalculator
{
  public const string FILE_INPUT = @"Kilo,Pound,0.45359237
                                     Kilometer,Mile,1.609344";


  private List<UnitMapping> mappings;

  public UnitCalculator()
  {
    this.mappings = new List<UnitMapping>();

    // parse the mappings
    foreach (var line in FILE_INPUT.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
      var fields = line.Split(',');

      var source = (Unit)Enum.Parse(typeof(Unit), fields[0]);
      var target = (Unit)Enum.Parse(typeof(Unit), fields[1]);
      double factor = double.Parse(fields[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

      this.mappings.Add(new UnitMapping(source, target, factor));
    }
  }

  public double Convert(Unit source, Unit target, double value)
  {
    foreach (var mapping in this.mappings)
    {
      if (mapping.SourceUnit == source && mapping.TargetUnit == target)
      {
        return value * mapping.Factor;
      }
      else if (mapping.SourceUnit == target && mapping.TargetUnit == source)
      {
        return value * (1 / mapping.Factor);
      }
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("No mapping could be found for this conversion.");
  }

}
```

Invoke it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var calc = new UnitCalculator();
  Console.WriteLine(calc.Convert(Unit.Mile, Unit.Kilometer, 1));
}
```

If you don't know the units, you can use strings as well.